# Automated Build & Deploy in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, visual-studio-2012

How should I specify my build definition in Visual Studio 2012 in order to build and deploy a SharePoint solution automatically?

Comment: When you right click on a solution and click deploy, it is automatically building and deploying?! Or are you talking about MSBuild scripts and continuous integration? For that you will need the Team Foundation Server.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about continuous integration and I have a TFS :) But I don't now how to deploy the solution automatically.

Comment: This is a really, really broad question. What have you tried? There are a ton of blog posts about this topic. Is there something about this process specifically you don't understand and/or you can't get to work?

Comment: I'm trying this blog at the moment:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/08/04/continuous-integration-for-sharepoint-2010-mike-morton.aspx
But I thought, there is maybe another blog for the current version of Visual Studio (2012).

Answer (score 0):

Although not VS 2012, this article series by one of my favorite bloggers can probably help you: http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2011/06/sp2010-continuous-integrationpt-1.html

Comment: I'm ready with step 4: Implementing assembly versioning. But I get this Error:  
TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \xxx\CI: The build controller cannot deserialize the process parameters of the build. Make sure the process parameters are compatible with the assemblies on the build machine. Details: Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow}AgileTestPlatformSpec'.